# Why sstable2json and json2stable is not there in Cassandra 2.1.12

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

`sstable2sjon` and `json2stable` utilities are not present in Cassandra 2.1.12. Is there anyway i could use them with the existing Cassandra version. Also, is there any limit on the size of parition which these utilities can handle to import and export data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It exists in [2.1.15](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/cassandra-2.1.15/tools/bin). Did you install from apt-get and include the cassandra-tools (`apt-get install cassandra-tools`) package? Otherwise, perhaps its not in your `PATH` or your install is broken though. try `locate sstable2json` and running with absolute path

Just to verify it is indeed there:

```
$ ar -x cassandra-tools_2.1.12_all.deb 
$ ls

cassandra-tools_2.1.12_all.deb control.tar.gz                 data.tar.gz                    debian-binary

$ tar xvfz data.tar.gz 
x ./
x ./usr/
x ./usr/share/
x ./usr/share/doc/
x ./usr/share/doc/cassandra-tools/
x ./usr/share/doc/cassandra-tools/changelog.gz
x ./usr/share/doc/cassandra-tools/copyright
x ./usr/bin/
x ./usr/bin/sstablemetadata
x ./usr/bin/sstablesplit
x ./usr/bin/sstablerepairedset
x ./usr/bin/sstablelevelreset
x ./usr/bin/sstable2json         <====================
x ./usr/bin/token-generator
x ./usr/bin/json2sstable
```

Comment: Thanks you very much chris